# Time Entry on IPhone

Tags: ios, ical

How can I enter times on an iPhone directly so that I do not have to go through the scrolling rotating standard time widget.

It is much quicker and easier to type 1545 rather than scroll from now until that time and fiddle about when you overshoot. I use Timer+ rather than the inbuilt timer to set alarms for say 20minutes for that reason but I can't choose alternatives in all cases e.g. Calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done at the moment. [UIDatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) has no standard option for typed dates/times and therefore it is down to the developer to implement such a thing. In the case of Apple's apps, they rarely go beyond the implementation available to others.

---

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html